# traefik generate wildcard certificate using traefik helm chart version `1.35.0`

Tags: lets-encrypt, traefik, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to generate wildcard certificate using the latest traefik helm chart version `1.35.0` this is the acme configurations but I can find in the logs that traefik request a certificate for each sub domain and no wildcard certificate seems to get requested

```
acme:
enabled: true
staging: false
email: info@mydomain.com
logging: true
challengeType: "dns-01"
dnsProvider:
  name: cloudflare
  cloudflare:
    CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL: "<EMAIL>"
    CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY: "<KEY>"
persistence:
  enabled: true
domains:
  enabled: true
  domainList:
    - main: "*.mydomain.com"
    - sans:
      - "mydomain.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be `domainsList` instead of `domainList`